# How to get height of Ext.Panel to fill parent area

Tags: extjs, extjs3, tabpanel

I have the following Ext.TabPanel:

```
var modules_info_panel = new Ext.TabPanel({
    activeTab: 0,
    defaults:{autoScroll:true},
    //layout: 'fit', // makes component disappear
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit:  true //has no effect
    },
    // height: auto, //error "auto isn't recognized"
    items:[{
            title: 'Section 1',
            html: 'test'
        },{
            title: 'Section 2',
            html: 'test'
        },{
            title: 'Section 3',
            html: 'test'
        }]
});
```

which looks like this:

[image]

**How can I get the line in the middle to extend down to the bottom so that it fills its parent space vertically?**

Here's how the TabPanel is loaded into `regionContent`:

```
regionContent = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'contentArea',
    region: 'center',
    autoScroll: true
});


function clearExtjsComponent(cmp) {
    var f;
    while(f = cmp.items.first()){
        cmp.remove(f, true);
    }
}

function replaceComponentContent(cmpParent, cmpContent) {
    clearExtjsComponent(cmpParent);
    cmpParent.add(cmpContent);
    cmpParent.doLayout();
}

replaceComponentContent(regionContent, modules_info_panel);
```

I see that the height is for this element in the dom is absolute (19px), where is that being set?

[image]

## Addendum

McStretch, I tried your idea by putting `layout: 'fit'` in the tabs themselves but the line still is in the same place:

```
var modules_info_panel = new Ext.TabPanel({
    activeTab: 0,
    defaults:{autoScroll:true},
    items:[{
            title: 'Section 1',
            layout: 'fit',
            html: 'test'
        },{
            title: 'Section 2',
            layout: 'fit',
            html: 'test'
        },{
            title: 'Section 3',
            layout: 'fit',
            html: 'test'
        }]
});
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated my response with the correct placement of layout: 'fit'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Corrected:**

Sorry Edward I was incorrect, you want `layout: 'fit'` within your **regionContent** Panel. The updated code changes are below.

Your initial idea of using `layout: 'fit'` is correct, but you have it in the wrong location. You want the following:

```
var regionContent = new Ext.Panel({
   region     : 'center',
   autoScroll : true,
   layout     : 'fit', // added this line
   items      : []
});
```

Comment: I tried that as in your code, but it didn't help, I added it to all of my tabs (code above) and it still had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are within a border Layout, how do you define the panel that set the border layout ? The center region of a border layout should normally fill the space not remained by the other regions. I did a sample that looks like your layout: http://jsbin.com/ikazo3/6/edit

From the [Border Layout](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.layout.BorderLayout) documentation:

> - Any container using the BorderLayout must have a child item with
>     region:'center'. The child item in the
>     center region will always be resized
>     to fill the remaining space not used
>     by the other regions in the layout.
> - Any child items with a region of west or east must have width defined
>     (an integer representing the number of
>     pixels that the region should take
>     up).
> - Any child items with a region of north or south must have height
>     defined.
> - The regions of a BorderLayout are fixed at render time and thereafter,
>     its child Components may not be
>     removed or added. To add/remove
>     Components within a BorderLayout, have
>     them wrapped by an additional
>     Container which is directly managed by
>     the BorderLayout. If the region is to
>     be collapsible, the Container used
>     directly by the BorderLayout manager
>     should be a Panel. In the following
>     example a Container (an Ext.Panel) is
>     added to the west region:

Comment: I finally realized that it was the `border: false` in your code which was making the difference, thanks!